# How can I implement a multi-line drop down select list with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a select list where some items in the list of choices are multi-line. I heard that there are some jQuery plugins that can help me out. If there's anyone out there with some experience of these I'd much appreciate some suggestions.

thanks,

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you mean that you are trying to make certain list item text wrap onto the next line?

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure what you mean either. Do you mean something like this? http://www.apycom.com/menus/12-steel-blue.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a simulation of a dropdown box using jQuery, instead of actually using a `<select/>` element. This is done all the time for Dropdown's in web navigation menus, so doing something similar in this instance would solve your issue.

Here are some references to get you started:

- [Drop Down on Link
  Hover](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/anylinkcss.htm)
  (see Demo #1)
- [38 jQuery Dropdown
  Menus](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/)